# How to create an apk file from an app file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I hired a developer to create an android app, and he sent me a folder of the app. But when i try to publish the app on google play, it wants a apk file. How do i compile the folder into an apk file?

Comment: You should hire me to release you an APK :D

Comment: just kidding, You need to know if it's gradle based or not. Is there any gradlew in this folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First way:**

1. Install Adroid Stuido
2. Install SDK
3. Open your app project in Android Studio
4. Click: Build -> Generate Signed APK. Create new key. Click: Next -> Finish.

You will have your .apk in project_folder\app\

**Second way (preferable):**
Ask your developer to send APK file.